# Getting generating set from fundumental domain

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory, group-actions

I'm reading *"Groups, Graphs and Trees" by Meier*.

In pages 31-34 (which could be found [here](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/01E9BE611625BCC9D417405820CD5E06/9781139167505c1_p1-43_CBO.pdf/cayleys_theorems.pdf)) He defined fundumental domain for group action on graphs as

**Defintion** Let $G\curvearrowright \Gamma$ be group acting on a connected graph. a set $F\subseteq \Gamma$ is called a *fundamental domain* if:

1. $F$ is closed
2. The set $\{g\cdot F | g\in G  \}$ covers the graph  $\Gamma$.
3. No proper subset of $F$ satisfies properties (1) and (2)

Then, a few pages after, there is the Theorem:
**Theorem 1.55** Let $G$ act on a connected graph $\Gamma$ with connected fundamental domain $F$. Then the set of elements
$$S = \{g\in G|g\ne e \ and \ g\cdot F\cap F\ne \emptyset\}$$
is a generating set for $G$.

I don't understand the proof of this theorem (the proof can be found in the link above) - the part that I don't understand is when the autor say:

"let $\{g_0F,...,g_nF\}$ be a finite sequence of (distinct) images of the
fundamental domain such that
$g_iF \cap g_{i+1}F \ne \emptyset $."

Why can we take such a sequence?
How can we be sure that there are two distinct $g,g'\in G$ s.t. $gF\cap g'F \ne \emptyset$?
In other words, how do we even know that the set $S$ is not empty?